# Looking for perl code to turn off data filter in Excel file

Tags: excel, perl

I've been reading an Excel XLSX file using [Spreadsheet::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX). Other people edit this file and tend to leave it with a column data filter turned on. Spreadsheet::XLSX doesn't have any way that I can find to turn off that filter, and the filtered state prevents my code from reading the rows which get filtered out. I found [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) which can turn off filters. But, it can't read Excel files, only write them. I also found Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX which doesn't look like it attends to column data filters either.

Comment: Can you provide a sample `.xlsx` file? Also provide a sample Perl script that reads the file and illustrates the problem. See [mcve] for more information